# Cannot install google-api-core package in our python app (Google Cloud Platform) due to conflicting dependencies (Python 3)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions

When I tried to install the Google Core API package, it always gets errors for every different version of this package. The app is run in Python 3, and I got the following logs:

```
The user requested google-api-core==1.21.0
    google-cloud-core 1.4.3 depends on google-api-core<2.0.0dev and >=1.19.0
    google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp] 1.29.0 depends on google-api-core 1.29.0
```

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 52) and google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

We want to install this package on the Google Cloud Platform.
Could somebody please help me with the conflicting dependency issue?

We tried the following packages but none of them work.

```
#google-api-core==1.29.0
#google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.0
#google-api-core==1.23.0
# google-api-core==1.19.0
# google-api-python-client==1.9.3
# google-auth==1.30.0
# google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
# google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
# google-cloud==0.34.0
# google-cloud-bigquery==1.25.0
# google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.0.1
# google-cloud-bigtable==1.2.1
# google-cloud-core #==1.4.3
# google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
# google-cloud-language==2.0.0
# google-cloud-logging==1.15.0
# google-cloud-pubsub==2.1.0
# google-cloud-resource-manager==0.30.2
# google-cloud-scheduler==2.2.0
# google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0
# google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
# google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
# google-cloud==0.34.0
# google-auth==1.22.1
#grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
#grpcio==1.29.0
# google-resumable-media
```

All the other related packages versions are as follow, and they are working:

```
google-api-core==1.21.0
google-api-python-client==1.6.7
google-auth==1.30.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.0.1
google-cloud-bigtable==1.2.1
google-cloud-core==1.4.3
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
google-cloud-language==2.0.0
google-cloud-logging==1.15.0
google-cloud-pubsub==1.7.0
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.30.2
google-cloud-scheduler==2.0.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
google-cloud-translate==3.0.1
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.0
google-cloud-vision==2.0.0
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
```

Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: The latest version of some Google Python libs don't work with Python 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think our code is run on Python 3. Do you have any insights into that? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Write these steps in your `requirements.txt` file:

```
google-api-core==1.29.0
google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.0
google-api-python-client==1.9.3
google-auth==1.30.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.25.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.0.1
google-cloud-bigtable==1.2.1
google-cloud-core ==1.4.3
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
google-cloud-language==2.0.0
google-cloud-logging==1.15.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.1.0
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.30.2
google-cloud-scheduler==2.2.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.29.0
google-resumable-media
```

Create a virtual environment and then install the dependencies. The steps for doing this are:

1. `python3 -m venv env`
2. `source env/bin/activate`
3. `pip list`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Hello Akshansha, thank you so much for your response! However, when I tried that, I have the following errors: "ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 90), -r requirements.txt (line 95), -r requirements.txt (line 98), google-api-core==1.29.0 and google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies." Could you please help me with that? A HUGE step forward though! Thanks again!

Comment: I have added the workaround in my recent answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below `requirements.txt` file. I have used the same, and it is working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: Still got an error. ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 51), -r requirements.txt (line 55), google-api-core, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.0, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.1, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.2, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.14.3, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.15.0, google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]==1.16.0... because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.